# Save and Listen a HashMap to/ from Firestore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to save and also listen a `Map<int, List<Object>> myMap;` from Firestore.

To do so, I have implemented within my repository the following method:

```
 @override
Future<void> set(LargerObject setLargerObject) async {
try {
  return _largeObjectCollection
      .document(setLargerObject.firebaseId)
      .setData(setLargerObject.toMap());
} catch (e) {
  return handleFirestoreError(e);
}
}
```

Within my `LargerObject` I am  using a

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
 return {
  'propertyA': propertyA,
  'myMap': myMap,
 };
}
```

method and the same for the `Object`. The problem is that I do not know how to properly map the **myMap** `Map<int, List<Object>>` within this method.

I am aware that Maps in Firestore have the following structure `Map<String, dynamic>` but how should I map the `List<Object>`?

Comment: Could you edit the question to be more specific about what you're trying to accomplish here?  It's kind of vague.  It would be helpful if you describe the problem your're trying to solve, show the data you're working with, and perhaps some code that isn't yet working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson Is this better or should I elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround to implement this.

I created instead a new class, and I am saving the HashMap entries into a List of type `NewClass` before saving them to Firestore. In the same manner when I am reading the data from Firestore, I transform them to a `Map<int, List<Object>>`.

```
static Map<int, List<Object>> transformListToMap(List<dynamic> hList) {
 Map<int, List<Object>> hMap = {};
 for (var listElement in hList) {
  hMap[listElement ['key']] = List.from(
      listElement ['objectList']
          ?.map((x) => Object.fromMap(x)));
 }
 return hMap;
}


static List<Map<String, dynamic>> transformMapToList(
  Map<int, List<Object>> myMap) {
   List<NewClass> hList = [];
   myMap?.forEach((key, value) {
    hList.add(NewClass(objectList: value, key: key));
   });
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> hHList = hList?.map((x) => x?.toMap())?.toList();
  return hHList;
}
```